# Replacing numbers in a text field upon typing new numbers using java script or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is suppose we have text box in an HTML form whose value for Example is 05/09/2013.Upon click of calendar icon I get that value in text box.

Now I click in the text box and type or change the value as 06/09/2013.Here while typing
if I press 6 then it should replace 5.(but when  I press 6 it should not be like 065/09/2013).If I press 6 it should replace 5.

So how to replace numbers upon typing using java script / Jquery.

I came know to that onKeypress() in javascript can be used.

But how to do proceed further?

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Okay, what should happen if you press `1`? Should that become `01/09/2013` or `15/09/2013`? (I'm assuming, obviously, that you're not using the American MM/DD/YYYY format, so `15` would be valid.)

Comment: I guess it should replace the first digit where the input would be valid... I have seen those kind of date inputs (don't know if on the web or elsewhere). If you want to enter 01 you would have to type 0 first and then 1. However, implementing this right could be kind of hard, as you would have to keep track of where in the field you are and should also reset this position if the user clicks somewhere else...

Comment: And to those downvoting and voting for closing it: I think this is a valid question, though it is not written that well. I guess @karthik is not a native speaker, so I'd recommend to cut him/her some slack...

Comment: I upvoted because I searched for months cause I was new and couldnt find a simple easy answer how. Hopefully my answer is easy to understand.

Comment: @SimonLehmann It obviously has __very low quality__, and it's not going to help anybody else solve whatever problem this may represent. I read it three times...

Comment: @likeitlikeit Low quality in writing? Yes, absolutely! But at least to me, this does not make a _question_ worthless. So, karthik, would you please try to say if how David Thomas and/or I understood your question is what you meant? If so, I might help you rewrite the question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I do this one of 2 methods,

Method 1.

```
 $(function() {
       var textinp = $('textfield').val();
      setInterval(function() {
        $('inputfield').val(textinp);
   }), 100);

});
```

or Method 2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('text').focusout(function() {
     $('input').val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Either one will work, I recommend 1. But to each its own.

Comment: Thanks Cam for your reply.If I have not stated question clearly, I will make it clear. If I have some value in text box example

Comment: Thanks Cam for your reply. I am sorry If I have not stated question clearly, I will make it clear. If I have some value in text box example "05/09/2013" if I want to change date value to "07/09/2013" OR any date value by typing in the number  should replace the one next to cursor.So the whatever number I  enter in text box should dynamically replace the number in text box as and when the cursor moves forward. I hope I made it little clear.

Comment: It sounds like you need to call an update to the next field. Can you create a jsfiddle.net with mockup code, and a layout of what your input fields will look like so I can help ya out.